# How to get rid of the <hr> vertical spacing?

Tags: html, css, margin, vertical-alignment, spacing

TLDR: click the bottom image and my noob problem becomes immediately evident.

---

Hi, all

I have two `<div>` elements that I want to separate with a `<hr class="separator">` element.

The CSS code for the `<hr class="separator">` element is as follows:

hr.separator { 
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

The CSS code for the bottom `<div class="brown">` element is as follows:

div.brown{
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 70px;
    background-color: #ce9771;
}

In the HTML code, these elements are set like this:

`<div>` upper div `\<div>`
`<hr>`
`<div>` bottom div `\<div>`

Still, I have a vertical whitspace (about 3px) between them. I've already tried to set all margins and padding to "0", and even played around with making the `<hr>`a child of each `<div>`and playing around with the position attribute (which invariably made the `<hr>`disappear).... Can anyone help a newbie here?

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide your HTML so I can see the problem reproduced?

Comment: @BeerusDev sorry, immediately after publishing, I noticed that I had forgotten it. I already edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With:

```
hr.separator {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

you only set/change the `top` border but the `hr` could also have other borders.

So first remove all borders with `border: none;` and then set the top border:

```css
hr.separator {
    border: none;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div.brown{
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 70px;
    background-color: #ce9771;
}
```

```html
<hr class="separator">
<div class="brown">

</div>
```

Whenever you have you don't know why something looks wrong you should check the computed properties of the style that is applied for that element in the developer tools of your browser.

Comment: tested it. worked. thanks everyone who tried to help... now, I have to wait 7 minutes before I can mark it as solved.

Comment: Question - assuming we didn't go with ```border: none``` can ```margin-bottom: -1px``` solve this as well? Or does that impose other problems?

Comment: @Brandon yes, but it interferes with other styling settings

Comment: @Brandon the question is, why do you want to hide a border that exists with a negative margin instead of removing the border. In addition to that how do you know the width of the border the browser applies as default to the `hr` element?